# Why must an abstract method be protected in a derived class?

Tags: c#, inheritance, abstract

When inheriting from an abstract class, why can't the protected abstract methods in an abstract base class be private when they are overridden in an abstract derived class?

Rephrasing, is it possible for an abstract method to be defined by a child abstract class, but then not accessible by a grandchild class?

Consider the simplified example:

```
public abstract class A
{
    // This method is protected - makes sense
    protected abstract void M();
}

public abstract class B : A
{
    // Why can't this be private?
    // Compiler forces it to be protected
    // but this means grandchildren classes always have access to this method
    protected override void M()
    {
        // Do something
    }
}

public class C : B
{
    // Is it possible for M() to be inaccessible here?
}
```

Comment: The fact that it's protected in the base class should mean it's accessible to all derived classes, whether that's directly or indirectly derived. Why would you *want* to do this?

Comment: @JonSkeet I don't have a specific scenario, just wondering if it is possible. This scenario would basically be like having a private method in a parent class who's logic is implemented by a child class. Again I can't think of a specific scenario but I could potentially see that being useful.

Comment: Why would you want `M` to be inaccessible anyway? You could prevent `C` from overriding `M` if you like by sealing it in `B`, is that what you actually want?

Comment: Reading between the lines a bit here: An option here is to use `protected internal`. That would still result in the behavior you're talking about for derived classes within your assembly, but would prevent the `protected` member from being accessed from external derivations. That's not specified in your question. But it's the most common case I can think of where you might want some derived classes to have access to `protected` members, but not others.

Comment: @JeremyCaney You can't change access modifiers to make them more limiting, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/9WqSqC Also I think you mean [`private protected`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/private-protected) which is only C#7.2 onwards

Comment: It wouldn't be possible to limit it, because a more derived class `C` could downcast itself back to `A` and still have access

Comment: @Charlieface: No, of course not. But you could obviously _start_ with the `protected internal` modifier to keep that member restricted to internal use, which is helpful assuming the concern is e.g. untrusted external derivatives calling into lower-level code (perhaps allowing them to bypass some business logic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible due to how inheritance works. All children (derived classes) have everything a parent has, plus whatever extra stuff you need.

That said - if you want a child class to NOT have one of the methods its parent has, you can do it with interfaces. Simply define an interface which lacks the one method you want to restrict, and have both parent and child implement it.

Comment: `private` methods are not inherited, so why inherit it and then change access method in a particular subclass? I wonder about inheriting the subclass or calling the base method.  [Access method is part of the method signature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods) if I read that correctly; so it seems that technically is not inheriting or overriding(?) the base method.

Answer (score 3):

The grandchild class C also implements the parent class A, so it's not possible. After all, in a program, you could cast any C object to a variable of type A, and you would expect to be able to call the M() method on it.
It would not make sense for a child class not to implement all the members of its parents, regardless of the inheritance hierarchy level.

Comment: I don't see this as a valid explanation because of course if `C` is cast to `A` then yes I agree you would expect to be able to call any *public* methods but not private/protected methods.

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889 Because `C` inherits ultimately from `A`, it can access any `protected` methods of `A`, so it could just downcast